# Adobe XD getting Error in sharing public link

Tags: hyperlink, adobe, share, adobe-xd, creative-cloud

I need to share my designs through link. But it kept getting stuck at 50%. I tried everything. Be it reinstalling cloud/ending from task manager/signin-signout/ export files. Everything works except the public share link. My internet connection is also good otherwise wont be able to do above things.[image]